# Script is not keeping attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

The search works fine, the problem is that when we search for something, it shows the corresponding `option` but it removes the `value` attribute, and when it deletes the search field it returns all items without the `value`.

How can I fix this so that it keeps the `value` attribute in `select > option`?

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var opts = jQuery('#list option').map(function() {
    return [[jQuery(this).text()]];
  });

  jQuery('#findItem').keyup(function() {
    var rxp = new RegExp(jQuery('#findItem').val(), 'i');
    var optlist = jQuery('#list').empty();

    opts.each(function() {
      if (rxp.test(this[0])) {
        optlist.append(jQuery('<option/>').text(this[0]));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
select,
input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="list" size="10">
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="2">Banana</option>
  <option value="3">Orange</option>
  <option value="4">Kiwi</option>
</select><br>
<input type="text" id="findItem">
```

Comment: well I do not see you setting the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the return in `opts`, it will return an array with the text and the value of the **option**.
`return [[jQuery(this).text(), jQuery(this).val()]];`

So, you can append the **value** here `optlist.append(jQuery('<option/>').text(this[0]).val(this[1]));`

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var opts = jQuery('#list option').map(function() {
    return [[jQuery(this).text(), jQuery(this).val()]];
  });

  jQuery('#findItem').keyup(function() {
    var rxp = new RegExp(jQuery('#findItem').val(), 'i');
    var optlist = jQuery('#list').empty();

    opts.each(function() {
    console.log(this)
      if (rxp.test(this[0])) {
        optlist.append(jQuery('<option/>').text(this[0]).val(this[1]));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
select,
input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="list" size="10">
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="2">Banana</option>
  <option value="3">Orange</option>
  <option value="4">Kiwi</option>
</select><br>
<input type="text" id="findItem">
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're destroying the original elements, along with their attributes, and appending new ones without any attributes.

To fix this you could store all the original `option` elements in a variable, then use `filter()` to match those containing the entered text and `append()` them back in to the `select`. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $opts = $('#list option');

  $('#findItem').keyup(function() {
    var rxp = new RegExp($('#findItem').val(), 'i');
    var optlist = $('#list').empty();

    $opts.filter(function() {
      return rxp.test($(this).text());
    }).appendTo('#list');
  });
});
```

```css
select,
input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="list" size="10">
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="2">Banana</option>
  <option value="3">Orange</option>
  <option value="4">Kiwi</option>
</select><br>
<input type="text" id="findItem">
```

Also note the aliased `$` inside the document.ready handler, so you don't need to use the verbose `jQuery` variable everywhere.